# JQuery with php showing div element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, nav

The problem is when I press left-nav "a" element it should `show()` me the div element, but its going to `hide()` it automatically. The "a" element is created with php and it has href of `?id=$product`, when I press class `closebtn` "a" element in side my navbar it `show()`'s me the div.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".sisu").hide();
    $('.vasaknav a').click( function() {
        $(".sisu").show();
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    $kask=$yhendus->prepare("SELECT id,Product from store GROUP BY Product");
    $kask->bind_result($id, $Product);
    $kask->execute();

    while($kask->fetch()){
        echo "<a href='?id=$Product' style='color:red;'>".htmlspecialchars($Product)."</a>";
    }
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Myvasaknav" class="vasaknav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <?php require('php/navlist.php'); ?>
    <a href=#  >test</a>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()" id="click">&#9776;</span>
```

Comment: After you click `a` redirect happens. And element becomes hidden.

Comment: When you click on a link with `href='?id=$Product'`, it reloads the page by opening that URL, so the Javascript on the current page has no effect.

Comment: Could you paste the generated HTML source? I wonder if your $Product is getting a value.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent default action when clicking `<a>` (which is reloading page / redirecting elsewhere) you should change your code like:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".sisu").hide();
    $('.vasaknav a').click( function() {
        $(".sisu").show();
        return false;   // prevent default action
    });
});
```

With this you will stay on the same page and `.sisu` element will be shown.

Comment: But how can I use my "if (isSet($_REQUEST["id"]))" if it prevents default a  actions

Comment: Not clear - how the flow should change if `request[id]` presents?